# Get part of array plus first element in numpy (In a pythonic way)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and i need to get (without changing the original) the same array, but with the first item places at the end. Since i am using this a lot i am looking for clean way of getting this.
So for example, if my original array is [1,2,3,4] , i would like to get an array [4,1,2,3] without modifying the original array.

I found one solution:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
a = np.append(x[1:],x[0])]
```

However, i am looking for a more pythonic way. Basically something like this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
a = x[(:1,0)]
```

However, this of course doesn't work. Is there a better way of doing what i want than using the append() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), as from the docs:

> Roll array elements along a given axis.
>
> Elements that roll beyond the last position are re-introduced at the
>   first.

```
np.roll([1,2,3,4], 1)
# array([4, 1, 2, 3])
```

To *roll* in the other direction, use a negative shift:

```
np.roll([1,2,3,4], -1)
# array([2, 3, 4, 1])
```

Comment: With `np.roll`, you need to remember which direction is positive and which is negative, though. I like the `append` version more, because it's a lot clearer which way it's rolling.

Answer (score 2):

`np.roll` is easy to use, but not the fastest method.  It is general purpose, with multiple dimensions and shifts.

Its action can be simplified to:

```
def simple_roll(x):
    res = np.empty_like(x)
    res[0] = x[-1]
    res[1:] = x[:-1]
    return res

In [90]: np.roll(np.arange(1,5),1)
Out[90]: array([4, 1, 2, 3])
In [91]: simple_roll(np.arange(1,5))
Out[91]: array([4, 1, 2, 3])
```

time tests:

```
In [92]: timeit np.roll(np.arange(1001),1)
36.8 µs ± 1.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [93]: timeit simple_roll(np.arange(1001))
5.54 µs ± 24.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

We could also use `r_` to construct one index array to do the copy.  But it is slower (due to advanced indexing as opposed to slicing):

```
def simple_roll1(x):
    idx = np.r_[-1,0:x.shape[0]-1]
    return x[idx]
In [101]: timeit simple_roll1(np.arange(1001))
34.2 µs ± 133 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```